# How to make image appear on another page via a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Complete novice at this, but I have an alert box linked to a html page, I need an image to be displayed in this page only once the link has been clicked. Have looked into cookies and local storage but i'm not getting anywhere.

Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>City Soldiers Question 1 Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="stickerbook.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width:480px)"/>

<script>

function correct() {
    var sticker = window.confirm("Correct! Go to Sticker Collection page.");
    if (sticker){
        window.location="GalleryCS.html";
    }
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id ="wrapper" >
    <div id ="logo">  
        <img src="mol_fulllogo.fw.png" alt= "Museum of Liverpool" width="400" height="106">
    </div>
    <div id ="mobilelogo"> 
        <img src="mol_logo.png" alt= "Museum of Liverpool" width="120" height="150">
    </div>
    <div id ="header"> 
        <h1> City Soldiers </h1>
        <h2> Question 1</h2> 
        <p align="center">What is the answer?</p>
    </div>

    <div id ="maincontent" >   
        <div id ="buttons">
            <p> <button type="button" onClick="correct()"> A </button> </p>
            <p> <button type="button"> B </button> </p>
            <p> <button type="button"> C </button> </p>
            <p> <button type="button"> D </button> </p>
            <p> 
                <a href="PickaQuestionCS.html">
                    <button type="button"> Go Back </button>
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What image? And where do you want to display it?

Comment: In addition, what is the link. It is properly to make a [tag:jsfiddle] demo.

Comment: want to display a basic png image on this page:

"GalleryCS.html"

which loads when ok is clicked in the alert box.

Comment: So you want to redirect to a new page, and show an image?  You can pass the image src as a query string parameter.  Or you can just have the image already in the new page if it's not dynamic.

Comment: It's important that the image is hidden until the correct link is clicked to that page

Comment: Than just pass a parm in the link, if that param is present then you will show an image otherwise keep it hidden. It is not wise to keep image somewhere and to pass it you actual can't pass it you would have to upload it to server that download it again. This is an option but it does not make much sense since you already have it on server.

Answer (score 0):

Working with values on different pages, you will most likely use a **query string**, **cookie**, or retrieve the image path from a **database**, **json**, or **xml**.